# Save aria2 generated .torrent file with magnet's "dn" name?

Tags: bash, torrent, magnet-uri, aria2

[Aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) has the ability to [specify a magnet URI and it will save a torrent file](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-bt-save-metadata). This file gets saved with a name of the hex encoded info hash with suffix `.torrent`.

[Magnet URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme#design) have an option for `?dn=`, which is a Display Name. Is it possible to use this name when saving the torrent, so that

```bash
aria2c -d . --bt-metadata-only=true --bt-save-metadata=true "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:cf7da7ab4d4e6125567bd979994f13bb1f23dddd&dn=ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
```

outputs `ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent` instead of `cf7da7ab4d4e6125567bd979994f13bb1f23dddd.torrent`?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any direct option, but there is a workaround

```
aria2c -S, --show-files[=true|false]
```

Print file listing of .torrent, .meta4 and .metalink file and exit. More detailed
information will be listed in case of torrent file.

Using this and some greping, cutting you could do something like this..

```
mv hash.torrent  "`aria2c -S hash.torrent | grep Name | cut -c7-`.torrent"
```